# Extend Bresenham's algorithm for second and fourth quadrant

Tags: c++, graphics, bresenham

I'm supposed to extend Bresenham's line algorithm for a university assignment so that it's able to draw lines in all octants. I was able to come up with working code for the first and third quadrant (so first, second, fifth and sixth octant). However I'm completely struggling getting it to work for the second and the fourth quadrant.

We're given this basic code on which to extend:

```
void Rasterizer2D::line( int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1 )
{
    // Bresenham algorithm (first octant only)

    // TODO: modify this function so it works for all octants
    int x = x0;  
    int y = y0;

    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int dy = y1 - y0;

    int delta_NE = 2*(dy - dx); 
    int delta_E = 2*dy;
    int d = (2*dy) - dx;

    while( x < x1 )
    {
        if( d >= 0 ) // NE
        {
            d+=delta_NE;
            x++; y++;
        }
        else // E
        {
            d+=delta_E;
            x++;
        }

        m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
    }
}
```

To solve this I started by thinking about what `dx` and `dy` are for each octant as well as if `dx > dy` because thereby we can tell how to apply the algorithm. For the parts of lines where the absolute of `dy` is more than the absolute of `dx` one should simply switch the roles of x and y so that we sweep over all points with single steps for y instead of x and define a new reference point to which the distance d gets measured. Hence I came up with the following code so far:

```
void Rasterizer2D::line( int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1 )
{
    // Bresenham algorithm (first octant only)

    // TODO: modify this function so it works for all octants
    int x = x0;  
    int y = y0;

    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int dy = y1 - y0;

    int delta_NE = 2*(dy - dx); 
    int delta_E = 2*dy;
    int delta_W = 2*(dx - dy);
    int delta_SE = 2*dx;
    int d = (2*dy) - dx;
    int d2 = (2*dx) - dy;

    //m_image.put( x, y, m_color );

    if (dx > 0) { //1 & 4
        if (dy > 0) { //first quadrant
            if (dx >= dy) { //first octant
                while( x < x1 )
                {
                    if( d >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d+=delta_NE;
                        x++; y++;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d+=delta_E;
                        x++;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            } else { //second octant
                while( y < y1 )
                {
                    if( d2 >= 0 ) // W
                    {
                        d2+=delta_W;
                        y++; x++;
                    }
                    else // SE
                    {
                        d2+=delta_SE;
                        y++;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            }
        } else { //fourth quadrant
            if (dx >= -dy) { //eigth octant
                while( x < x1 )
                {
                    if( d >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d+=delta_NE;
                        x++; y--;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d-=delta_E;
                        x++;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            } else { //seventh octant
                while( y > y1 )
                {
                    if( d2 >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d2+=delta_W;
                        y--; x++;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d2-=delta_SE;
                        y--;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (dy >= 0) { //second quadrant
            if (dx < -dy) { //fourth octant
                while( x > x1 )
                {
                    if( d >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d+=delta_E;
                        x--; y++;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d+=delta_NE;
                        x--;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            } else { //third octant
                while( x > x1 )
                {
                    if( d >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d-=delta_E;
                        x--; y++;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d+=delta_E;
                        x--;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            }
        } else { //third quadrant
            if (dx > dy) { //sixth octant
                while( y > y1 )
                {
                    if( d2 >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d2-=delta_W;
                        x--; y--;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d2-=delta_SE;
                        y--;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            } else { //fifth octant
                while( x > x1 )
                {
                    if( d >= 0 ) // NE
                    {
                        d-=delta_NE;
                        x--; y--;
                    }
                    else // E
                    {
                        d-=delta_E;
                        x--;
                    }

                    m_image.put( x, y, m_color );
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However the problem I'm facing right now is that I tried every possible combinations of `d+=` and `d-=` also in regard to the references `delta_NE`, `delta_E`, `delta_W` and `delta_SE` but none of them seem to work. The current code provides me with this image:

[image: result]

It's obvious to see that the code for the eight octant seems to go into the right direction but for whatever reason it just doesn't draw the right lines. Obviously the x-coordinate of the endpoint of the lower pink line in the eight octant lines up with that of the green line that is the angle bisector of the first quadrant. However it's clear to see that in contrast to that green line the pink one is NOT an angle bisector of the fourth quadrant. So what would am I missing for a correct appraoch or are my considerations for solving this completely off in general?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You should debug your code and inspect / print out the intermediate values to see if they make sense instead of looking at the images drawn.  If one or more of those numbers stand out, then you know where to look for either a correction, or a different approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that advice. I'll have a look at it tomorrow and update this as soon as I could figure out any new findings.